# Can't connect to router without restarting it

Tags: router, wireless-router

I have a problem with our wi-fi router. Whenever the internet is down, my computer gets disconnected from the router. When I try to reconnect to the wi-fi network, Windows tells me it "cannot connect to the network." I have to restart the router before I can connect to the network.

**Is there a way to avoid having to restart the router every time the internet connection goes down?**

I have encountered this problem on multiple computers (Windows 10) with multiple routers. Although not always the case, whenever the internet connection goes down, I need to restart the router in order to reconnect to the internet.

One fix I have tried before is by going to "Network Connections" and disabling/enabling the network adapter. This worked for my personal laptops, and I am able to connect to the wi-fi network without restarting the router. However, I am using a company laptop and disabling/enabling the adapter requires elevated privileges.

I just want to avoid having to restart the router every time, which is really inconvenient. I live in a country where the internet connection is not very reliable

Comment: Could you please share the router brand and model?

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/www.whatimade.today/make-an-automatic-router-re-starter-for-3-with-an-esp8266-01-and-single-relay/amp/

Comment: how old is the router? What you describe is kind of how they die. I usually give consumer grade routers about 3 years.

Comment: @wasifhasan novel!